# Installation failed in Ghostscript on Windows XP

Tags: php, wampserver, ghostscript

I want to convert PDF to images in PHP. For that I installed Ghostscript and also imagick but it's a failure. I am using a WAMP server.

If I run my code means it will not work so I didn't install the software successfully...

Can anyone please guide, how to install the Ghostscript on my WAMP server on Windows XP.

The past two days I was struggling for this installation. DLL file also failed.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your code doesn't work doesn't necessarily mean the software failed to install. In fact you haven't presented any evidence that it did fail. Did you get any error messages during installation ?

Can you run Ghostscript and ImageMagick from the XP command shell ? If not, what errors do you get ?

If the applications work from the command shell, then you have 2 obvious possibilities:

1) The environment is different when running your PHP server, you should check the PATH environment variable at the very least, but compare the entire environment you are using vs the command shell environment.

2) Your code has a bug which prevents it working. Again, do you get any error codes ?

The question as you've presented it can't be answered because there isn't enough iniformation. The only answer I can give to your question is 'use the Installer Luke'

Comment: there is no error during my installation and also my code run. i think  PATH environment only problem. where i need to install the GhostScript and ImageMagick.. i need to install in WAMP path or anywhere? And i need the perfect match DLL file for the both GhostScript and ImageMagick.

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $pdf='gsuresh.pdf';
    $quality=90;
    $res='300x300';
    $exportName="pdf_export_" . time();
    $exportPath=realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/$exportName/fullres/%03d.jpg";
    
    mkdir(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/$exportName");
    mkdir(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/$exportName/fullres");
    
    set_time_limit(900);
    exec("'gs' '-dNOPAUSE' '-sDEVICE=jpeg' '-dUseCIEColor' '-dTextAlphaBits=4' '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4' '-o$exportPath' '-r$res' '-dJPEGQ=$quality' '$pdf'",$output);
    
    for($i=0;$i<count($output);$i++)
    echo($output[$i] .'<br/>');

Comment: You should be able to install GS and IM anywhere, and the PATH environment variable, if correctly set, will allow you to execute the applications from anywhere. If GS and IM work from the command line, then the PATH is correct, and its your 'WAMP' environment which is incorrect. I can't tell you how to fix that.